# Why is my document library content not being shown?

Tags: document-library, view

I have a SharePoint 2007 site where the main user has just reported that her folders are missing for a document library.  I have no idea what the history of this document library is or what happened to cause this, but now the list is not rendering properly.  The list title is shown, but the list description and the New, Actions, and Settings menu is not there, and the contents of the list aren't shown either. I can go to this library in Windows Explorer and see the folder and file contents, and everything seems to be there.  What would cause this to disappear?

What can I do to restore this view?

[image: Missing description and menus]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone has either closed or deleted the list view web part.

Try appending ?Contents=1 to the end of the URL and see if the web part is closed.  If it does not show up, then edit the page and add the document library web part back to that document library.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue the other day. Someone closed the webpart. Edit the page, click on add a webpart, go to Advanced Webpart Gallery and Options at the bottom, then closed webparts and readd the webpart. Otherwise it was deleted and needs to be readded.